# How to use iron-node to debug jest unit tests?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, javascript-debugger, iron-node

To run my UTs I run the command:

```
BABEL_JEST_STAGE=0 jest
```

**How can I use iron-node to debug my unit tests?**

btw, my package.json has a standard jest configuration:

```
  "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
    "testFileExtensions": [
      "es6",
      "js"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "es6"
    ],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "react"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote a doc about how to debug grunt tasks. With a good chance you can apply this technique to debug jest.

https://github.com/s-a/iron-node/blob/master/docs/DEBUG-NODEJS-COMMANDLINE-APPS.md